# RealVNC screen updates are taking 4-7 seconds to update, when before it was milliseconds

Tags: raspbian-buster, vnc

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 4 running a version of Raspbian.

[image: Raspbian version information]

I'm hard-wired into a little hub that is connected to a powerline adapter that is connected to my ISP's router in the other room. However WiFi seems to be turned on also, and both adapters are passing traffic. If I turn off WiFi then I can't connect to the Pi using RealVNC.

Most of the time I use RealVNC from a laptop. Recently the pi lost connection to the network, so using a wireless mouse and a keyboard and a monitor plugged directly into it I restarted the pi.

I'll list some of the symptoms I'm now seeing.

- VNC Server was not starting automatically (pretty sure it was before) so I ran raspi-config and turned it on, then rebooted a couple of times, and it is fine.
- I had a couple of panels in the top-right that showed CPU temperature and usage. Those had disappeared.
- Screen updates to RealVNC are taking 5-6 seconds. I can see the monitor and if I open a terminal window (for example) then it appears in a second on the monitor but can take 5-7 seconds to appear in the VNC client on my laptop
- when I open a terminal window and typw ping 1.1.1.1 I get regular "Destination Host Unreachable" messages, usually in clumps of 2, every 10 seconds or so. This wasn't like this before. (see screenshot) [image: screenshot of ping timeouts]

HTop looks like this [image: HTop command screenshot]

Thanks in advance of pointers I can check.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Please describe the structure of your network in more detail. Are both laptop and Raspberry Pi connected to the hub or one to the hub and the other to the router? Is the router the WiFi access point? Are both laptop and Raspberry Pi connected to both WiFi and wired network? How exactly do you specify the address of the Raspberry Pi when using RealVNC? Does the Raspberry Pi get two different IP addresses and maybe DNS names for WiFi and wired network?

Answer (score 0):

You have a network problem. Too much is unclear about your set-up to give a definitive solution. So, these are the first few steps I would do to search for the problem.

First, if you really have a hub between the Pi and the powerline adapter, replace it with a switch or directly connect the Pi to the powerline.

There is no reason why the Pi should not listen to the cable connected network (unless you've done something there). Of course, the calble connected IP address wil be different from the WiFi IP address. You should be able to see both addresses with `ifconfig -a` or `ip addr`.

So, there are a lot of unknowns here. The `ping` from time to time produces Destination Host Unreachable. When you force the `ping`  through the wired connection (`-I eth0`, unless you've enabled "predictable" interface names), does it behave also that way? or does the powerline plug loose connection from time to time? In that case, check that powerline thing.

And if you force the `ping` through WiFi, does that continue to work well, or are there lapses as well? In that case, download an app for a wifi-analyzer on your phone and check if the WiFi signal is sufficient.It may be that a neighbour has recently placed a new, much stronger, WiFi access point on the same band that you are using.

What happens if you ping the gateway instead of 1.1.1.1? Same destination unreachables? If not: then there might be an issue with your ISP router.

Oh, and PLEASE, do not post pictures of text; in stead cut-and-past the text. We're not fans of the `.norm` file format here. (https://xkcd.com/2116/)